# Is there a way to generate columns from an existing column for a specific primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Azure SQL Database.

I want to generate 3 columns from an existing column for a specific primary key.

For example:

```
id = 1
data = 'name=john&age=17&height=160'
```

=>

```
id = 1 
data =  'name=john&age=17&height=160'
name = john
age = 17
height = 160
```

I don't have the regex option available and I tried some CHARINDEX, substring and string split functions from AZURE but with no positive outcome.

Comment: Will the `data` string **always** contain all 3 parameters (`name`, `age`, and `height`) and always in the same order?

Comment: Also, what is the **exact column type** of `data`?

Comment: It will always contain those 3 parameters, in the same order. The data is of type string

Comment: `string` is not a column-type in Azure SQL / SQL Server.

Comment: Also, **don't store ages in databases**: it's time-sensitive data that goes stale within a year. If you _must_ store an age value then you **need** to store the `date` when that was their age (e.g. data-entry-date).

Comment: sorry, it is a varchar type

Answer (score 0):

- Using `CHARINDEX` will work, I don't know why it didn't work for you.

---

Setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (
  
  id     int         NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  "data" varchar(50) NOT NULL
  
);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable ( data )
VALUES
( 'name=john&age=17&height=160'          ),
( 'name=lukeskywalker&age=19&height=175' );
```

Work:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD
    name   nvarchar(100) NULL,
    age    int           NULL, /* <-- This is a bad idea: don't store ages in databases. */
    height int           NULL;

---

WITH part1 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        "data",
        NULLIF( CHARINDEX( 'name='   , data ), 0 ) AS nameStartIdx,
        NULLIF( CHARINDEX( '&age='   , data ), 0 ) AS ageStartIdx,
        NULLIF( CHARINDEX( '&height=', data ), 0 ) AS heightStartIdx
    FROM
        dbo.MyTable
),
part2 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        "data",
        nameStartIdx   + 5 AS nameValueStartIdx,
        ageStartIdx    + 5 AS ageValueStartIdx,
        heightStartIdx + 8 AS heightValueStartIdx,

        NULLIF( CHARINDEX( '&', "data", nameStartIdx + 5 ), 0 ) AS nameValueEndIdx,
        NULLIF( CHARINDEX( '&', "data", ageStartIdx  + 5 ), 0 ) AS ageValueEndIdx,
        NULLIF( LEN( "data" ), 0 ) + 1 AS heightValueEndIdx /* +1 is needed because CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING are 1-based, not 0-based. */
    FROM
        part1
),
part3 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        "data",

        SUBSTRING( "data", nameValueStartIdx  , nameValueEndIdx   - nameValueStartIdx   ) AS "name",
        SUBSTRING( "data", ageValueStartIdx   , ageValueEndIdx    - ageValueStartIdx    ) AS "age",
        SUBSTRING( "data", heightValueStartIdx, heightValueEndIdx - heightValueStartIdx ) AS "height"
    FROM
        part2
    WHERE
        nameValueStartIdx IS NOT NULL
        AND
        ageValueStartIdx IS NOT NULL
        AND
        heightValueStartIdx IS NOT NULL
        AND
        nameValueEndIdx IS NOT NULL
        AND
        ageValueEndIdx IS NOT NULL
        AND
        heightValueEndIdx IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE
    t
SET
    name   = q.name,
    age    = q.age,
    height = q.height
OUTPUT
    inserted.*
FROM
    dbo.myTable AS t
    INNER JOIN part3 AS q ON q.id = t.id
--WHERE
--    name IS NULL
;
```

DBFiddle proof: https://dbfiddle.uk/lSsw_7wy